# How to port Lwuit application to Blackberry Torch

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I have developed a Lwuit application and I ported that same app to blackberry bold,curve,storm
but when I gonna port that very same application to blackberry torch it doesnt work and gives
illegal state exception. So I want to know how to port my app to blackberry torch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use latest [LWUIT](http://java.net/projects/lwuit) repository or download [LWUIT 1.5.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) They created separate LWUIT jar file for blackberry domain. you can use that jar file for your blackberry application. More info look here, [LWUIT with Blackberry.](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Resource Editor for LWUIT 1.5 to redevelop your app - it will surely make it easier this time around. I suggest this because after development, you can generate a netbeans project, that usually contains sub-projects in 4 platforms - Desktop, MIDP, Blackberry and Blackberry touch. I am sure your problematic platform will be covered as well.